# Using Spring boot with oauth2 but facing some issue

Tags: java, spring, jpa, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring boot with oauth2 but getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class
 [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration];
 nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
```

I think there is some version issue with the dependency in the pom file. But i am not able to figure out. I am new to Spring boot. Please help me to solve this issue..

My POM looks like as below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>InventoryManagementAndBillingSystemFE_V2</groupId>
  <artifactId>InventoryManagementAndBillingSystemFE_V2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Spring ORM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- c3p0 -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Spring security dependency -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

      <!--   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>-->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      <!-- Spring security dependency ends-->
      <!-- Jackson API for JSON -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
       <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
   <tomcat.version>8.0.43</tomcat.version>
 </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src.main.java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your pom seems weird. The goal of spring boot is to have version managed by the starters, it seems like you are doing the job twice, e.g if you include `spring-boot-starter-web`, why are you adding `spring-webmvc`, maybe you need to run `mvn dependency:tree` and do some analysis.

Comment: yes i know but i tried many things and so this looks weird...but anyhow pom not giving any error but once i run the application Tomcat server does not start..can you please tell some solution for the actual problem that i have mentioned...

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V` So versions of Spring at compile time and runtime are inconsistent. QED

Comment: so what should i do..any suggested solution ???

Comment: What should you do? Make the versions of SPRING consistent at compile time and runtime!!!!

Comment: can someone help me please??? Tried many thing but not working...

Comment: Finally i resolved the issue. I deleted all the jars from the repository folder and then again did the Maven update to download the dependencies. It worked for me. I did it few times then it worked and i also removed many of the dependencies that i had exclusively mentioned in the POM file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved the issue. I deleted all the jars from the repository folder and then did the Maven update to download the dependencies. It worked for me. I did it few times then it worked and i also removed many of the dependencies that i had exclusively mentioned in the POM file.